# Bash Named Pipe - Atomic Reading

Tags: bash, pipe, aix, fifo

I have set up one script to write to a named pipe, then four scripts to read the named pipe.

For most of the entries, there are no problems, but when there is little processing to be done on the lines of input, some of the reads start to conflict with each other and the resulting text is a combination of random characters from (up to) 4 lines for the (up to) 4 processes.

The reason I can't use xargs or parallel, is that in the connection time to the database takes 1 second, which adds up as there are usually ~1300 lines that need to be processed.

Example Output:

> Completed Runstats on MAIN.MK37 in 1s: DB20000I  The RUNSTATS command completed successfully.
>
> Completed Runstats on MAIN.MKAP in 0s: DB20000I  The RUNSTATS command completed successfully.
>
> Completed Runstats on MAIN.MKAL in 0s: DB20000I  The RUNSTATS command completed successfully.
>
> Completed Runstats on MAIN.MK49 in 0s: DB20000I  The RUNSTATS command completed successfully.
>
> Failed Runstats on AI.K1MAIN after 0s: SQL2306N  The table or index "AI.K1MAIN" does not exist.
>
> Failed Runstats on MNM5. after 0s: SQL0104N  An unexpected token "MNM5." was found following "TBLE".  Expected
>   tokens may include:  "".  SQLSTATE=42601
>
> Completed Runstats on MAIN.MK50 in 0s: DB20000I  The RUNSTATS command completed successfully.
>
> Completed Runstats on MAIN.MK52 in 0s: DB20000I  The RUNSTATS command completed successfully.

Writer:

```
# Open pipe for writing
exec 10>"${PIPE_LOCATION}"

# Feed data
while read LINE; do
    echo "${LINE}" >&10
done <<< "${LIST}"

# Tell threads to stop
i=0
while [ "${i}" -lt 4 ]; do
    echo "stop" >&10
    (( i += 1 ))
done

# Close pipe
exec 10>&-
```

Reader:

```
# Open Pipe
exec 10<"${PIPE_LOCATION}"

while read -u 10 -r SCHEMA TABLE; do
    if [[ "${SCHEMA}" == 'stop' ]]; then
        break
    fi

    #
    # Runstats Code Here
    #

done

# Close Pipe
exec 10<&-
```

Is there some way to make the reads atomic?

I was thinking I could coordinate the main thread like a server, and the four readers could send it a request every time it wanted some input, which would probably solve the problem (5 pipes instead of 1, though!), but if there's an easier solution someone can suggest, I'm all ears!

Comment: Quoting from `man bash`: "Redirections using file descriptors greater than 9 should be used with care, as they may conflict with file descriptors the shell uses internally."

Comment: I think the only reasonable way to make this work is to write and read fixed-sized records.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I could try padding them with whitespace. I'll try that, and see.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, thanks for the heads up! I'll try this as well.
EDIT: Tried 5 instead of 10 (on both scripts), still received errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MarkPlotnick had the right idea.
I changed the script to pad the line with spaces and make read use fixed-size records.

Note: File descriptor is now 5 instead of 10, due to @Hauke Laging's findings

I now feed the data like so:

```
# Feed data
while read LINE; do
    printf "%64s" "${LINE}" >&5
done <<< "${LIST}"
```

And read it like so:

```
while read -u 5 -N 64 -r LINE; do
    LINE=(${LINE})
    SCHEMA=${LINE[0]}
    TABLE=${LINE[1]}
```

and there are no more errors!

Comment: The shell's `read` command is a performance nightmare. May not matter in your situation but in general something like `awk` is more suitable.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Thanks for the heads up. It's already about 50% faster and is a lot nicer on the database from it's original implementation, so I'm not too worried. I'll try to keep this info in the back of my mind if I ever need to revisit or refactor something else.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - while I agree about the shell, `awk` is pretty crazy slow compared to a real performer - such as `dd`. It comes with a read/write pas argument as well - with `conv=sync`. It's designed for this work.